# Para que servem os métodos "bind" e "bindTo" de uma Closure?

Tags: php

Estava fazendo uns testes com funções anônimas em PHP. Eu já sabia que as funções anônimas era uma instância de uma classe interna chamada `Closure`.

Fiz um testes para saber se ela tinha métodos e percebi que tinha dois:

```
$a = function () {};

var_dump(get_class_methods($a));
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "bind"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "bindTo"
}
```

Quais são as finalidades desses métodos `bind` e `bindTo` numa `Closure`?

Comment: Olá, você pode consultar facilmente direto na documentação oficial do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.closure.php Rolando um pouco logo vem a seção **Sinopse da Classe** onde relaciona os métodos, e logo abaixo na seção **Índice** tem a documentação de cada método ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL ; DR**

- Duplica a `Closure` usando uma nova instância para a pseudo-variável `$this` e um novo escopo;
- Parâmetro `$newthis`: alterar o objeto vinculado (bound) a pseudo-variável `$this` da `Closure`;
- Parâmetro `$newscope`: alterar o escopo da `Closure` para a pseudo-variável `$this` e, em consequência, a visibilidade dos métodos `protected` e `private`;
- `bind` é um método estático e `bindTo` é um de instância.

**Explicação**

Infelizmente, não há como fazer desta uma resposta curta e direta, pois, envolve muitos casos e situações. Entretanto, irei listar os dois mais comuns e linkar os demais que são "mais raros" de se encontrar.

Ambos possuem o mesmo intuito, alterar a pseudo-variável `$this` e o escopo de uma `Closure`. Apenas uma é `static` e a outra não.

Basicamente, toda `Closure` criada dentro de uma classe recebe automaticamente o escopo da classe. Resumidamente, ela pode utilizar a pseudo variável `$this` e acessar métodos e propriedades `protected` ou `private` fora da classe em que foi criada.

Do [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

> As of PHP 5.4.0, when declared in the context of a class, the current class is automatically bound to it, making $this available inside of the function's scope. If this automatic binding of the current class is not wanted, then static anonymous functions may be used instead.

Então, utilizando a classe abaixo:

```
class Foo
{
    private $number;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function getClosure()
    {
        return function() {
            echo $this->number;
        };
    }        
}
```

E executando o seguinte código:

```
$foo = new Foo(10);
$closure = $foo->getClosure();
$closure();
```

Teremos a saida:

> 10

O número 10 é correspondente a variável `$number` privada da classe `Foo` da instância `$foo`.

Utilizando a troca de escopo, pode-se obter resultados diferentes, acessando a mesma variável de outra instância, tal qual:

```
$foo = new Foo(10);
$foo2 = new Foo(50);
$closureFoo = $foo->getClosure();
$closureFoo();//Primeira execução

echo ' and ';

$closureFoo2 = $closureFoo->bindTo($foo2);
$closureFoo2();//Segunda execução
```

E o resultado será

> 10 and 50

Para o uso de `bind`, o código seria o seguinte:

```
$closureFoo2 = Closure::bind($closureFoo , $foo2);
```

O resultado `10` se refere a variável `$number` da instância `$foo`. Por outro lado, o resultado `50` se refere a variável `$number` da instância `$foo2`. Alterando o escopo da `Closure`, foi possível **ter acesso** a variável privada de **outra instância da mesma classe**.

`BindTo` e `Bind` possuem, respectivamente, um segundo parâmetro e terceiro, denominado `newscope`. Esse parâmetro deve ser utilizado quando o tipo da classe que será utilizado mudar e existe a necessidade de acessar alguma variável `private` ou `protected`.

Adicionaremos uma classe nova, com exatamente a mesma estrutura:

```
class Bar
{
    private $number;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function getClosure()
    {
        return function() {
            echo $this->number;
        };
    }
}
```

E com o exemplo abaixo:

```
$foo = new Foo(10);
$bar = new Bar(50);
$closureFoo = $foo->getClosure();   
$closureBar = $closureFoo->bindTo($bar);
$closureBar();
```

Obteremos o seguinte erro:

> FATAL ERROR Cannot access private property Bar::$number on line number 15

Perceba que as classes `Foo` e `Bar` possuem exatamente a mesma estrutura, excetuando-se que são classe distintas. Sendo a visibilidade da variável `$number` da class `Bar` privada, ela fica inacessível para a `Closure` que possui o escopo da classe `Foo`.

É importante ressaltar que o escopo de visibilidade do PHP é delimitado a classe e não a instância. Dessa forma, um objeto pode ter acesso a métodos e variáveis `protected` ou `private` de outra instância, contanto que ambos sejam da mesma classe. Como pode ser visto no link abaixo:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects

Ao compreender como funciona a resolução de escopo entre instâncias de uma mesma classe, é possível compreender como a troca de escopo de instâncias diferentes, de um mesmo objeto, não afeta a `Closure`. Entretanto, quando a troca é para um objeto diferente, não é possível ter o mesmo resultado, mesmo que a estrutura da nova classe seja idêntica a primeira.

Para ter acesso a variável, deve-se fazer uso do parâmetro `newscope`

```
$closureBar = $closureFoo->bindTo($bar , $bar);
```

E obteremos o resultado desejado:

> 50

Informando que o novo escopo da `Closure` é `Bar` e não mais `Foo`, a `Closure` terá acesso as variáveis `protected` e `private`. O mesmo comportamento ocorre com métodos `protected` e `private`.

Apenas a título informativo, o escopo não necessariamente precisa ser um instância, pode ser, também, das seguintes formas:

```
$closureBar = $closureFoo->bindTo($bar , 'Bar');//PHP >= 5.4
$closureBar = $closureFoo->bindTo($bar , get_class($bar));//PHP >= 5.4
$closureBar = $closureFoo->bindTo($bar , Bar::class);//PHP 5.5
```

Existem outras situações que ocorrem que devem ser entendidas, entretanto, o post ficaria muito mais extenso do que já é. Para esse caso, deixo dois links  (ambas respostas minhas), um sobre uma situação com `Reflection`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772386/how-can-i-invoke-a-reflectionfunction-wrapping-a-closure-that-utilizes-this/40772588#40772588

e outra sobre como alterar a `Closure` entre objetos/instâncias não altera seu escopo (está em grupo aberto de estudo sobre a ZCPE 5.5):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rumo-a-certificacao-php/3ZL_f-51nYk/X_1Gd-ldEgAJ